# Is there any way to comment or document tables or columns in Azure Data Warehouse?

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database

I'm looking for a way to add documentation to tables and columns in Azure Data Warehouse. I tried `sys.sp_addextendedproperty` and it isn't available there. Looking through the documentation I don't see any mention of this sort of thing. Has anyone found another way of documenting tables and columns?

Answer (score 1):

Extended properties is a feature already considered by Azure SQL Data Warehouse team as explained on the following URL:

https://feedback.azure.com/forums/307516-sql-data-warehouse/suggestions/16317988-table-extended-properties

To my knowledge, there is no current alternative to help store metadata of database objects or self documenting to aid BI developers using Azure SQL Data Warehouse.